# iOS isActiveNetworkMetered api

Tags: ios, networking

I'm developing an iOS app which needs to know whether the cellular network is metered to save the cost,  do we have an api in iOS to get the information?

In android the api is [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#isActiveNetworkMetered()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#isActiveNetworkMetered%28%29).

> Returns if the currently active data network is metered. A network is classified as metered when the user is sensitive to heavy data usage on that connection due to monetary costs, data limitations or battery/performance issues. You should check this before doing large data transfers, and warn the user or delay the operation until another network is available.

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 0):

There is no check exactly to check like network is metered or not but you can check whether the network connection is via cellular or wifi.

You can use the [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) class provide by apple here

Then implement the following to find whether you have connected on cellular

```
- (BOOL)networkCheckForCellular
 {
    Reachability *wifiReach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [wifiReach currentReachabilityStatus];

    switch (netStatus)
    {
        case NotReachable:
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",@"NETWORKCHECK: Not Connected");    
            return false;
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",@"NETWORKCHECK: Connected Via WiFi");       
            return false;
            break;
        } 
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",@"NETWORKCHECK: Connected Via WWAN");
            return true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
 }
```

Comment: this solution didn't solve the problem @iPrabu. Any one have experienced this problem?